# Multiple tags for the same thing GWTP & GWT-Platform

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

How should multiple tags be handled for the same thing?

In StackOverflow, I have the [gwtp](/questions/tagged/gwtp) and the [gwt-platform](/questions/tagged/gwt-platform) tags.

They both refer to the same thing.

Should they be merged? I notice something called synonyms but it requires some specific privileges.